# What does the attribute error 'numpy.nadarray' object has no attribute 'isnull' mean?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, numpy-ndarray, attributeerror

I am trying to find the total number of missing values in my dataset. I have imported both pandas and numpy libraries but I keep getting this attribute error message
'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'isnull'

This is my code

```
print(data.isnull().sum().sum())
```

Comment: Numpy arrays don't have a "isnull" method but pandas dataframes do. Do you expect `data` to be a pandas dataframe?

Comment: The error implies that `data` is in fact a `numpy.ndarray`. You seem to think it is a `pd.DataFrame`. So, maybe try: `pd.DataFrame(data).isnull().sum().sum()`.

Comment: We don't have enough of the error message to know if this line caused the error, or how `data` was assigned in the first place. Assuming its that line, `data` is an instance of `numpy.ndarray`, which does not have a method `isnull`. If you have any question about that, you'll need to update this post.

Comment: Yes, I expected my data to be a pandas dataframe and I assigned it as such earlier.I tried the code you sent. It worked. Thanks so much for your superb explanation

Comment: Thank you sm @tdelaney. The error was in that line of code. I appreciate your help

Comment: Attribute errors are usually the result of the actual object class being different from the expected.  Most commonly the wrong object is a `None`.  In any case, when you get an error like this, check the class.  Why is an array instead of the expected dataframe?  Turing it back into a frame may fix the problem, but doesn't address the root cause - what assigned a new object to `data`.